# If $f(x)$ is a continous function such that $f(x) +f(\frac{1}{2}+x) =1; \forall x\in [0, \frac{1}{2}]$ then $4\int^1_0 f(x) dx =$ .

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Problem :

> If $f(x)$ is a continous function such that $f(x) +f(\frac{1}{2}+x) =1; \forall x\in [0, \frac{1}{2}]$ then $4\int^1_0 f(x) dx = ?$

My approach :

$$f(x) +f(\frac{1}{2}+x) =1 \tag{1}\label{1}$$

Let us put $x = \frac{1}{2}+x$ we get

$$f(\frac{1}{2}+x) +f(1+x) =1 \tag{2}\label{2}$$

$\eqref{1}-\eqref{2}\Rightarrow f(x) -f(1+x) = 0$

$\Rightarrow f(x) = f(1+x)$

Is it the correct method to find $f(x)$?  Please guide thanks.

Comment: What about, just $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$?...in either case, you are just integrating $\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)+f(x+\frac{1}{2})dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}1dx=\frac{1}{2}$...times four is 2.

Comment: If you put x = x + 1/2 you are no longer in the interval where f(x) + f(1/2 + x) = 1.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use $\displaystyle\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2} }f(x)dx+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1f(x)dx;\;\;$ then let $u=x-\frac{1}{2}$ in the second integral.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
  &4\int_0^1 f \\
  =& 4\int_{0}^{0.5} f(t) dt + 4 \int_{0.5}^1 f(t) dt\\
  =& 4\int_{0}^{0.5} f(t) dt +  4 \int_0^{0.5} f(x+\frac12) dx \quad\text{($x = t - \frac12$)}\\
  =& 4\int_{0}^{0.5} (f(t) + f(t+\frac12)) dt\\
  =& 4\int_{0}^{0.5} 1 dt\\
  =& 4\cdot 0.5\\
  =& 2
\end{align*}